# Image to image mapping in keras

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I am new to machine learning. I have a 2D array(image) need to be mapped into another 2D array(image). All examples are using a `Dense` layer with output of 1, in classification problem. But, my problem is simple mapping and image to another image. 
How can I specify that output 2Darray(image) in keras. Please find below, a sample code. I need to change the architecture to give me an output of same size as input(2Darray).

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Activation, Dropout, Flatten, Dense

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=(3, 150, 150)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Flatten())  # this converts our 3D feature maps to 1D feature vectors
model.add(Dense(64))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is some autoencoder symmetrical structure. Unlike normal architectures, your output will be in 3D because you have pictures as output. You then fit the model with the same data as input/output. Here's a simple example with generated data:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Dropout, UpSampling2D
import numpy as np

input = np.random.rand(10, 30, 30)

input = input[..., None] # keras needs 4D input, so add 1 dimension

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=(30, 30, 1), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(UpSampling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(1, (3, 3), activation='sigmoid', padding='same'))

model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')

model.fit(input, input, batch_size=8, epochs=1)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's really helpful

Comment: Note that the checkmark is not an upvote, but indicates that the answer is a solution to the problem. As such, you can only give it once per post. [_you may accept the answer that you believe is the best solution to your problem._](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: One more question. I am still confused about that example. I am trying to do a 2D example similar to this, but still confused.            My input image:   30*30, I have 10 training images                                                                   My output image: 30*30.                                                               Sorry to ask this, but can you show me how to make it applicable to this example. In your example when I predict, it requires the full 4D matrix

Comment: Of course. I edited the example. Keras needs 4D input, however. So, you need to add a dimension to your pictures to make it work. It just cannot handle 3D input.

Comment: Sorry again to bother. But when I select only on image out of the 10. to predict it is giving me error, required the full 10.                                                                                         p      = Input[0,:,:,:]
pred = model.predict(p)                                                                                                    So, I need to use the full 4D matrix everytime ??

Comment: Yes, Keras needs 4D input to use convolutional layers.